# Transición (spinner) tras pulsar un enlace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Muy buenas, estoy buscando hacer una pequeña animación mientras se carga la página para que el usuario sepa que se está cargando. He encontrado este hilo que está genial y lo explican bien y fácil: [¿ Como crear transición mientras carga una pagina?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125205/como-crear-transici%C3%B3n-mientras-carga-una-pagina)

El script que usa es este:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
    $(".loader-page").css({visibility:"hidden",opacity:"0"})
  }, 2000);
});
```

Pero tengo un problema, la animación solo se carga mientras el script espera a que se termine de cargar la página. Pero cuando el usuario pincha un enlace existe un tiempo mientras el usuario espera la respuesta del servidor, que a veces pueden ser unos segundos.

¿Podría de alguna forma hacer que la animación se cargue mientras espera al servidor?

Muchísimas gracias y saludos!

Comment: Cuando dices "cuando el usuario pincha un enlace existe un tiempo mientras el usuario espera la respuesta del servidor", ese "click" es manejado por Javascript / Ajax?

Comment: En principio me refiero a cualquier elemento tipo <a></a> por lo que debería poder ser manejado por Javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Probando he dado con esta solución creo que es bastante válida, aunque no se si podrá dar problemas con los enlaces de ancla.

```
$(function() {

    $("a").on('click', function () {
            $(".loader-page").css({visibility:"visible",opacity:"1"})
    });
    $("input[type=submit]").on('click', function () {
            $(".loader-page").css({visibility:"visible",opacity:"1"})
    });

});
```

Si alguien tiene alguna forma mejor genial, sino espero que sirva a alguien :D